# Return an array of movie objects by connecting two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have a collection of User, Movie, and Wishlist.

A user is already stored in a variable ***user_email*** and I would like to get all the **movie** objects that have the same id as the one stored in **wishlist**. Here are some schemas and data types:

Sample:

```
user_email: shangchi@gmail.com
```

**Movie**
Movie Schema:

```
const movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    image: String, 
    title: String, 
    rating: String, 
    length: String, 
    // timeslots: Array
    timeslots: [{
        id: Number, 
        time: String, 
        seats: []
    }]
});
```

Movie Data Sample:

```
_id: 61d65a3431a314f4fc7e9170
image: "https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2021/08/25/spence..."
title: "Spencer"
rating: "R"
length: "1 hr 57 min"
timeslots: Array
__v: 0
```

**Wishlist**
Wishlist Schema:

```
const wishlistSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    user: String, 
    movie: Schema.ObjectId
}
```

All Data in Wishlist:

```
_id: 61ea4e67984f981ee529c008
user: "shangchi@gmail.com"
movie: 61d65a3431a314f4fc7e9170
__v: 0

_id: 61ecf6f6c7b93b96890c9ebb
user: "shangchi@gmail.com"
movie: 61e3a7bed4f5306388103156
__v: 0

_id: 61ecf73c9f651a07079c9641
user: "hello@gmail.com"
movie: 61e3acc21d84993477d89a22
__v: 0

_id: 61ecf73e9f651a07079c9644
user: "hello@gmail.com"
movie: 61d65a3431a314f4fc7e9170
__v: 0
```

How do I get an array of all the movie objects that matches all the *movies* with the shangchi email in the **Wishlist** collection?

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: Yes I am. But I can't seem to figure out how this will go.

Comment: You can run a find query with populate on movie on Wishlist collection. Query would look  something like this - const movies = await Wishlist.find({ user: "shangchi@gmail.com" }).populate("movie", null, "Movie")

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great! I have posted an answer below with the same approach. Please accept it so your question can be marked solved and other people can also see the solution.

Comment: My bad!!! Already did. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using mongoose, you can perform a simple find query on Wishlist collection with populate on movie field.

```
const wishlistMovies = await Wishlist.find({ 
  user: "shangchi@gmail.com" 
}).populate("movie", null, "Movie")
```

This will return a list of wishlist movies for user with email shangchi@gmail.com where movie id will be replaced by the Movie document.

Answer (score 0):

With [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#-lookup--aggregation-).

```
db.movie.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "wishlist",
      let: {
        movieId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$movie",
                    "$$movieId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$user",
                    "shangchi@gmail.com"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "wishlist"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qN-rHLeBnJR)

---

### Reference

[Perform Multiple Joins and a Correlated Subquery with `$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup)